# Open folder in Explorer from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I have a project/folder open in VS Code and I want to open the folder in Windows Explorer, is there keyboard shortcut or a VS Code Extension for that? Sometimes I also need to go to the project folder in command prompt.

In Visual Studio 2017, there's a menu option to open the folder and an extension for quickly getting to the project folder in command prompt -- see below:
[image]

How do I handle these in VS Code?

Comment: Opening the command prompt (on a mac) `cmd + shift + p` opens the list of possible commands.  Searching for "reveal" or "explorer" may show the shortcut on windows as well.

Comment: You can also use command ```open .```(mac) or ```explorer .```(windows) in vs code terminal. It will open your work directory, to print it you can use ```pwd``` command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right click on a file or folder from the left side explorer of VSCode, then select "Reveal in Explorer".  Now you can see the folder in windows explorer.

Comment: using mouse may be fine for some, but is there a command that can be bound to a key combo?

Comment: The default keyboard command is `shift + alt + r`. However, note the when condition on the command. It has the value `!editorFocus`, so pressing this command will not work from the editor (unless you remove the when condition).